# core dump in basic_string.tcc - optimized out

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, stdstring, coredump

Occasionally I experience some core dumps which i can't figure out why they happen. Typically this happens when assigning av value to a string. Below is the backtrace for one of this cases. A core dump seems to be caused by this line in my c++ code:

```
m_strValue = "---";
```

I can't figure out what is going on in this case and I home someone can shed some light over this issue.

Below is the backtrace

```
#0  0x40227ed4 in *__GI_raise (sig=6) at ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:67
#1  0x402293d0 in *__GI_abort () at abort.c:92
#2  0x4011a594 in __gnu_cxx::__verbose_terminate_handler () at /home/habbjack/ssd/workspace/builder2/build_armv5l-linux-gnueabi/gcc-4.5.3/gcc-4.5.3/libstdc++-v3/libsupc++/vterminate.cc:93
#3  0x40118770 in __cxxabiv1::__terminate (handler=<optimized out>) at /home/habbjack/ssd/workspace/builder2/build_armv5l-linux-gnueabi/gcc-4.5.3/gcc-4.5.3/libstdc++-v3/libsupc++/eh_terminate.cc:39
#4  0x40118798 in std::terminate () at /home/habbjack/ssd/workspace/builder2/build_armv5l-linux-gnueabi/gcc-4.5.3/gcc-4.5.3/libstdc++-v3/libsupc++/eh_terminate.cc:49
#5  0x40118914 in __cxxabiv1::__cxa_throw (obj=<optimized out>, tinfo=<optimized out>, dest=<optimized out>) at /home/habbjack/ssd/workspace/builder2/build_armv5l-linux-gnueabi/gcc-4.5.3/gcc-4.5.3/libstdc++-v3/libsupc++/eh_throw.cc:83
#6  0x400c8de8 in std::__throw_length_error (__s=<optimized out>) at /home/habbjack/ssd/workspace/builder2/build_armv5l-linux-gnueabi/gcc-4.5.3/gcc-4.5.3/libstdc++-v3/src/functexcept.cc:74
#7  0x400fe02c in std::string::_Rep::_S_create (__capacity=4294967293, __old_capacity=<optimized out>, __alloc=<optimized out>) at /home/habbjack/ssd/workspace/builder2/build_armv5l-linux-gnueabi/gcc-4.5.3/gcc-4.5.3-stage3/armv5l-linux-gnueabi/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/basic_string.tcc:552
#8  0x400fe260 in std::string::_M_mutate (this=0x7d3d78, __pos=0, __len1=9, __len2=3) at /home/habbjack/ssd/workspace/builder2/build_armv5l-linux-gnueabi/gcc-4.5.3/gcc-4.5.3-stage3/armv5l-linux-gnueabi/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/basic_string.tcc:479
#9  0x400fe3fc in std::string::_M_replace_safe (this=0x7d3d78, __pos1=0, __n1=<optimized out>, __s=0x62d708 "---", __n2=3) at /home/habbjack/ssd/workspace/builder2/build_armv5l-linux-gnueabi/gcc-4.5.3/gcc-4.5.3-stage3/armv5l-linux-gnueabi/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/basic_string.tcc:684
#10 0x400fe48c in std::string::assign (this=0x7d3d78, __s=<optimized out>, __n=3) at /home/habbjack/ssd/workspace/builder2/build_armv5l-linux-gnueabi/gcc-4.5.3/gcc-4.5.3-stage3/armv5l-linux-gnueabi/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/basic_string.tcc:264
#11 0x0026175c in CLCD_Wnd::Refresh (this=0x7d3d60) at ../../lib/src/HAL/LCD/CLCD_Wnd.cpp:49
```

Comment: Problems like this are almost always the result of memory corruption caused at an earlier point in the program's execution. The string likely had its pointer overwritten to reference garbage memory, so naturally when it attempts to write to itself, it gets a SEGV. You're on ARM so unfortunately you can't use Mudflap or valgrind, but you could at least compile with -g3 -O0 and use a debugger to step through and see where you start to stray beyond the pale. If you can run off-target, try valgrind and it'll notice your errant write...

Comment: I think you will find [Valgrind](http://www.valgrind.org/) useful.

Answer (score 1):

Line 7 show creation with capacity=4294967293 followed immediately by throw_length_error.

Plus, your object at line 11 is only 24 bytes away from your string, which may indicate some kind of allocation problem if CLCD_Wnd needs more space than that.

Answer (score 0):

Almost certainly `m_strValue` or its containing object no longer exists (deleted or went out of scope). It's impossible to say without more code but if you're on Linux valgrind can help you out.